# Why i am getting gradle syntax error after installing "Android Studio Giraff"?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I recently had to update my Android Studio. Now, I have the Android Giraff version, everything seems fine for the first run. But, after I tried to implement new dependencies to gradle, the IDE is not recognizing the syntax in many lines.

In fact, it doesn't recognize the syntax anymore, and I have no idea why this is happening because it should load automatically the standard dependencies like Data Binding and Navigation, but it doesn't.

Why is this different now, and what am I doing wrong?

The project is a simple new "Empty View Project", I'm not using Compose. So, this seems really strange.

Maybe someone knows this issue already after installing the new Android Studio Giraff, any help would be welcome thanks a lot!

Here a few screens what it looks like:

[my module gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE6yV.png)

[my project gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgK8H.png)

Also, I noticed that it no longer recognizes the old syntax:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
```

Instead, it only works with parentheses:

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
```

Comment: You've switched from `build.gradle` (which uses the Groovy language) to `build.gradle.kts` (which uses the Kotlin language). It's therefore not surprising that you get errors, trying to parse Groovy code using Kotlin.

Comment: You saved my day, thank you very much for youre response. That solved my Problem! :)